# Jquery complaining syntax error - Json coming from a asp net mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

From this call

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Manage", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Você tem certeza que deseja salvar a alteração?", OnSuccess = "close" }))
```

the OnSuccess function is called and execute the following:

```
    function close(json) {
    $('"#' + json.param1 + '"').dialog("close");
    alert(json.Message);
}
```

and I get this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#UserSettings"
```

[Break On This Error]

throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

`$('#UserSettings').dialog("close");` works fine so I don´t get why the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the extra double quotation marks in your jQuery selector.  It should be:

```
$('#' + json.param1).dialog('close');
```

Comment: No problem.  The reason it was complaining was because it thought you were looking for `$('"#UserSettings"')` which is an invalid selector.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#' + json.param1).dialog("close");
```

The double-quotes I think is where you are having an issue.